# How to add multiple arguments in FormatMessage() with va_list?

Tags: c, winapi

I have a function like the following:

```
void test() {
    char lpBuffer[MAX_PATH];
    LPVOID pv = NULL;
    va_list Environment = (va_list)malloc(MAX_PATH);
    Environment = (va_list)"abc";
    FormatMessageA(0x2500, "%1\\test.exe", 0, 0, (LPSTR)&pv, 0, &Environment);
    printf("%s\n", pv);
}
```

This `test()` function prints `abc\test.exe`. Now I want to add more strings after it from function parameters. For example,

```
void test(char* var) {
    ...
    Environment =(va_list)"abc";
    ...
    ...
    FormatMessageA(0x2500, "%1\\test.exe %2", 0, 0, (LPSTR)&pv, 0, &Environment);
    printf("%s\n", pv);
}
```

Now the function should print `abc\test.exe var` but that does not work. I've read the [`FormatMessage()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351(v=vs.85).aspx) documentations. How can I do that?

Comment: That's not how you make a `va_list`. You use the `va_start` macro to make a `va_list`. But you don't need a `va_list` for this. Use `FORMAT_MESSAGE_ARGUMENT_ARRAY`.

Comment: va_start va_end ?

Comment: If you are new, why don't you do some research. A websearch gives you all you need. Type va_list into a search engine. It's really important that you learn how to use websearch. Without that skill you will struggle to progress.

Comment: In that case it's pointless anyone writing an answer. If you can't understand http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic/va_list then you won't understand any answer here. I actually don't believe you made any effort to read these topics. You can't hope to have any success if you won't put effort in.

Comment: And as Raymond says, you don't need that anyway, you can just follow the instructions in the documentation for FormatMessage. You have to stick at things. Don't give up after 30s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`va_list` is a opaque object type and its implementation depends on the operating system and/or compiler. It is often just a location on the stack but you cannot assume that.

The valid way to get a `va_list` is from a variadic function:

```
int myfunc(const char*fmt, ...)
{
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, fmt);
  // use args va_list here.
  va_end(args);
}
```

With FormatMessage it might look like this:

```
LPSTR FormatMyMessage(const char*fmt, ...)
{
  int ret;
  LPSTR str;
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, fmt);
  ret = FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER|FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_STRING, fmt, 0, 0, (LPSTR) &str, 0, &args);
  va_end(args);
  return ret ? str : NULL;
}

...

LPSTR str = FormatMyMessage("%1\\test.exe %2", "abc", "def");
if (str)
{
  MessageBoxA(NULL, str, NULL, 0);
  LocalFree(str);
}
```

If this pattern does not suit you then you cannot use a va_list.

Luckily for you the `FormatMessage` function also supports parameters in a simple array when you use the `FORMAT_MESSAGE_ARGUMENT_ARRAY` flag:

```
DWORD_PTR params[2] = { (DWORD_PTR) "abc", (DWORD_PTR) "def" };
char*str;
if (FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ARGUMENT_ARRAY|FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER|FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_STRING, "%1\\test.exe %2", 0, 0, (LPSTR) &str, 0, (va_list*) params))
{
  MessageBoxA(NULL, str, NULL, 0);
  LocalFree(str);
}
```

For simple string formatting like this you can also use [`wsprintf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647550(v=vs.85).aspx) but it will not allocate memory for you.

Comment: "*For simple string formatting like this you can also use `wsprintf` but it will not allocate memory for you*" - true. But you can use `snprintf()` instead, which allows you to calculate the necessary memory size so you can allocate your own memory.